# Leetcode - First Unique Character in a String

Tags: java, programming-challenge, array, interview-questions

> Given a string, find the first non-repeating character in it and
> return its index. If it doesn't exist, return -1.

**Examples:**

```
s = "leetcode"
return 0.

s = "loveleetcode",
return 2.
```

> Note: You may assume the string contain only lowercase letters.

My solution

```
public class FirstUniqueCharacter {

    public int firstUniqChar(String s) {
        LinkedHashMap<Character, Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();

        for (char c : s.toCharArray()) {
            if (Objects.isNull(map.get(c))) {
                map.put(c, 1);
            } else {
                int count = (Integer) map.get(c);
                map.put(c, ++count);
            }
        }

        for (Map.Entry e : map.entrySet()) {
            int value = (int) e.getValue();
            Character c = (Character) e.getKey();
            if (value == 1) {
                return s.indexOf(c);
            }
        }

        return -1;
    }
}
```

The statistics shows it’s still slower than 60% of the solutions submitted in terms of speed and space. How can I improve it?  Any comments regarding code readibility are most welcome.

Answer (score 2):

You don’t need `Objects.isNull(...)`.  Simply using `!= null` would suffice, and avoids an extra function call so should be faster (unless the compiler can optimize the call out).

---

Your loop at the end is using raw types.  You should use

```
for(Map.Entry<Character, Integer> e : map.entrySey()) {
```

instead, for type safety.  Your castings then are unnecessary.

---

There is no need to fetch the character `c = e.getKey()` unless `value == 1` is true; you can move that inside the `if` for a minor performance gain.

---

Counting the character occurrences is slightly dangerous: you could overflow an `Integer`, or even a `Long` with a long enough string.  Simply flagging the character as “seen once” or “more than once” avoids the counting overflow bug.

---

The `map.put(c, 1)` call returns the previous value stored in the map, or `null` if no value was stored.  Instead of fetching the value, testing whether it was present or not, and then storing another value, why not store & fetch in one operation?  Then, if a value was already present, you can flag it as occurring twice (or more).

```
if( map.put(c, 1) != null )
    map.put(c, 2);
```

---

Since you are no longer counting, you don’t need a `LinkedHashMap<Character, Integer>`.  You just have 3 states: not seen, seen once, and seen more than once.  A `Boolean` can cover this.  `Boolean.TRUE` is seen once (unique), `Boolean.FALSE` is seen more than once, and not present (`null`) is never seen.

```
LinkedHashMap<Character, Boolean> unique = new LinkedHashMap<>();

for(char c: ...) {
    if (unique.put(c, Boolean.TRUE) != null)
        unique.put(c, Boolean.FALSE);
}
```

We’ve saved a tiny bit of space, since we only have two `Boolean` objects, instead of several (possibly interned) `Integer` objects.  Much more importantly, we’ve avoided auto boxing, so this should be much faster.

---

We are still wasting time storing both `Boolean.TRUE` and `Boolean.FALSE` successively on the third and subsequent occurrences of any character.

If we always store `Boolean.FALSE`, then on the first occurrence `null` will be returned.  We can detect that and overwrite it with `Boolean.TRUE` instead, so the exceptional first occurrence has 2 map `put` operations, but subsequent occurrences only use 1 map `put` operation, for better performance.

```
    if (unique.put(c, Boolean.FALSE) == null)
        unique.put(c, Boolean.TRUE);
```

---

To truly gain speed and reduce memory usage, avoid clunky `HashSet<>` memory structures, and store the data yourself.  You are told you can assume only lowercase letters are used, so you can use a `new byte[26]` array for “not seen”, “seen once”, and “seen multiple times” storage.  And use a `new char[26]` array to maintain encounter order of “first seen” characters.

You can use a bit more memory and store the index of the first seen characters in a `new int[26]`, so you can avoid the linear `s.indexOf(c)` search at the end.  You could even use `0` for not seen, `index+1` for seen once, and `-1` for seen multiple times, and avoid the `new byte[26]` flag storage.

Comment: Never assume that a "letter" means something between a-z. https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/category/Ll    Regards, Your Scandinavian fellow

Comment: @TorbenPutkonen The task description explicitly says you can assume that.

Comment: @RoToRa Actually it says “_You may assume the string contains only lowercase letters._”.   It doesn’t say anything about ‘a-z’.   On the other hand , it doesn’t mention the vulgarities of [Unicode combining characters](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character).   The “C” version of the problem uses `char *` for its strings, but that doesn’t preclude multibyte character encodings either.  Even with ‘a-z’ restrictions, using EBCDIC encoding would complicate the storage into just 26 array entries.  Using `byte[256]` storage would be better, but still wrong for some encodings.

Answer (score 0):

Having `LinkedHashMap` A and `HashSet` B.

For each character C in string S

- Map C to its position in S to A.
- If adding C to B returns false
- Remove C from A.

Return value mapped to first element in A or -1 if A is empty.